# How to make a react js element by using props?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, string-concatenation

I have a functional element in react js like this,

```
function FilterOptions() {
  const [isShown, setIsShown] = useState(false);
  return (
    <div className="filter__options">
      {["Category", "Design", "Size", "Style"].map((ourOption) => (
        <div
          onMouseEnter={() => setIsShown(true)}
          onMouseLeave={() => setIsShown(false)}
          className="filter__options__container"
        >
          <div className="filter__options__button">
            {ourOption}
          </div>
          {isShown && <div className="filter__options__content">  Here I want to return the element using props </div>}
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

I have created a files called, Category.js, Design.js, Size.js, Style.js.
Now I want to use the props so that I can concatenate like this `<{ourOption}> <{ourOption}/>` so that this will return element.
Any idea how to do this guys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Choosing the Type at Runtime](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#choosing-the-type-at-runtime)

First: Import the components used and create a lookup object

```
import Category from 'Category';
import Design from 'Design';
import Size from 'Size';
import Style from 'Style';
// ... other imports

const components = {
  Category,
  Design,
  Size,
  Style,
  // ... other mappings
};
```

Second: Lookup the component to be rendered

```
function FilterOptions() {
  const [isShown, setIsShown] = useState(false);
  return (
    <div className="filter__options">
      {["Category", "Design", "Size", "Style"].map((ourOption) => {
        const Component = components[ourOption];
        return (
          ...
            <div className="filter__options__button">
              <Component />
            </div>
          ...
        ))}}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Alternatively you can just import and specify them directly in the array to be mapped.

```
function FilterOptions() {
  const [isShown, setIsShown] = useState(false);
  return (
    <div className="filter__options">
      {[Category, Design, Size, Style].map((Component) => (
        ...
          <div className="filter__options__button">
            <Component />
          </div>
        ...
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of strings you could iterate over Array of Components

```
{[Category, Design, Size, Style].map((Component) => (
    <Component/>
);
```

Comment: I don't think we can do this.
I am not able to do that.
And also I want it to be string because I also have to return a string in one place.

Comment: ohh okay @Adithya I got this.
Thanks for helping

Comment: Glad to be of help, [heres](https://codesandbox.io/s/sad-lake-jtz9d?file=/src/App.js) a sandbox showing you could iterate over components. also if you want name also, you can iterate over array of objects and have name in each object

Answer (score 1):

Ill do this as [react document](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#choosing-the-type-at-runtime)

```
//create components array
const components = {
    photo: Category,
    video: Design
    .....
};

{
    Object.keys(components).map((compName) => {
        const SpecificSection = components[compName];
        return <SpecificSection />;
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a small sample code that you can work with. Use direct component instead of trying to determine by strings.

```
const Comp1 = () => {
  return <p>Comp1 Here</p>
}

const Comp2 = () => {
  return <p>Comp 2 Here</p>
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {[Comp1, Comp2].map(Komponent => { 
        // use Komponent to prevent overriding Component
        return <Komponent></Komponent>
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image]